# What is the best practice to change farm account in SharePoint server 2019

Tags: 2019

What is the best practice to change farm account in SharePoint server 2019?
can I use CA>Security>ConfigureManaged account and register new managed account and after the change farm account from_admin/FarmCredentialManagement.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper method to update the farm credentials (change account or update the password) is to use `stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials`. For example:

`stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin CONTOSO\FarmAccount –password farmPassword`

Comment: the above command will work in Sharepoint 2019?

Comment: Yes, while `stsadm` is deprecated, there are commands that are not available via PowerShell.